# Simple CrossRider extension doesn't work

Tags: crossrider

I have the following in the `background` scope, it should print the active tab info to the console every 10 seconds:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {

    // console information about active tab every 10 seconds
    appAPI.setInterval(function() {
        appAPI.tabs.getActive(function(tabInfo) {
            console.log(
                'tabId: ' + tabInfo.tabId +
                ' tabUrl: ' + tabInfo.tabUrl
            );
    });}, 10 * 1000);
});
```

And it doesn't give anything in the console, on the latest Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you checking Chrome's background console? For more information, see [Viewing Messages in Chrome's Background Console](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/guide/howto_console_log-section-5).

FYI: I tested your code on the latest Chrome and it works as expected:
[image: Test Result]

[**Disclaimer**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at that documentation section requiring `Developer Mode`. I thought the normal console would be enough. Thank you :)